# Are Metaheuristics Global Optimizer?

Tags: optimization, metaheuristics, global

In recent years, we experience an explosion in the publication of metaheuristics. They claim finding the **global** optimum of the optimization problems they are applied on.

Is that claim correct? Can metaheuristics, they are after all heuristics, determine global optima?

Comment: Could you give the references of some of these publications?

Comment: @fontanf I am sorry, I am not going to do this.

Comment: Why not? it's difficult to comment about a reported claim. The exact statement as well as the context may change the interpretation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like any heuristic they can locate global optima, but they can't prove that they are global.

Comment: Hi Nikos. I share of course your opinion but what bothers me is that all the authors or users, ok lets say very many, of such metaheuristics claim to have determined the global optimum of their problem. These are peer reviewed papers and I am asking myself how come that the reviewers accept such claim. Are you aware of any referenceable scientific publication stating that metaheuristics do not guarantee global optimality?

Comment: @Clement I don't think that the "burden of proof" is on people who say that meta-heuristics doesn't guarantee global optima. Rather I would ask people who claim that meta-heuristics produce global optima to provide a proof for their claim. That being said, I often see papers with sentences like "Our <something>-inspired meta-heuristic produce global optima in *many* of our test instances". Here, I suppose, the authors know global optima from other sources, and compare their results to the known optima.

Comment: @sune This is what I mean. How come that scientists claiming in their publications to have determined global optima, by using metaheuristics are not challenged to provide proof. On the other hand a scientific publication showing that metaheuristics cannot, in general, determine global optima, would provide clarity.

Comment: @Clement People can know whether a solution is globally optimal through other means, e.g. from the physics of the problem or by cross-referencing with solutions/objective values that are already known to be globally optimal (e.g. for library problems).

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct. From all of the papers I have read on metaheuristics, if they claim that they have found a globally optimum solution, then they are either running it on an known benchmark instance, or they solved it with an exact method for comparison. Sometimes you test your metaheursitic on toy instances, prove it can at least find a global optima there (by calculating the exact answer with your favourite solver), and then test it on instances where we only have approximate lower or upper bounds.

If any decent optimization algorithm can explore the **entire** search space, then it will eventually find a global optima, given enough time. The problem with metaheuristics and heuristics is that they limit the search space in order to find a good solution quickly (which could still be optimal). It is this "hole" in the search that means whatever local solution they give you is not necessarily globally optimal.

Comment: But finding the global optimum on test cases doesn't make these algorithms, meta heuristics, global optimizers. They still are heuristics. They can fail on many other instances.

Comment: About "searching the entire search space": Yep, I agree: our Exhaustive Search algos do exactly that. They prove the optimal solution. They are also utterly useless in the real world because of the search space size :) "Metaheuristics can't prove optimality." is true.

Comment: @Clement yeah but it serves as kind of a sanity check. If it doesn't work well on easy things,(so the logic goes) then it probably won't work well on hard things. At the end of the day, for a lot of problems, proving something is globally optimal is not important. If you want to get nitpicky, the model is probably unrealistic and the data is probably flawed. Also you can always give the metaheuristic's solution to a branch and bound solver and see if it can get an optimal solution from there